# Get intersection of two maps with different values in Kotlin

Tags: unit-testing, collections, kotlin, functional-programming

I have two lists: one with old data where a `Boolean` should preserved, and new data that should be merged with the old data. This can best be seen by this unit test:

```
@Test
fun mergeNewDataWithOld() {

    // dog names can be treated as unique IDs here
    data class Dog(val id: String, val owner: String)


    val dogsAreCute: List<Pair<Dog, Boolean>> = listOf(
            Dog("Kessi", "Marc") to true,
            Dog("Rocky", "Martin") to false,
            Dog("Molly", "Martin") to true
    )

    // loaded by the backend, so can contain new data
    val newDogs: List<Dog> = listOf(
            Dog("Kessi", "Marc"),
            Dog("Rocky", "Marc"),
            Dog("Buddy", "Martin")
    )

    // this should be the result: an intersection that preserves the extra Boolean,
    // but replaces dogs by their new updated data
    val expected = listOf(
            newDogs[0] to true,
            newDogs[1] to false
    )

    // HERE: this is the code I use to get the expected union that should contain
    // the `Boolean` value of the old list, but all new `Dog` instances by the new list:
    val oldDogsMap = dogsAreCute.associate { it.first.id to it }
    val newDogsMap = newDogs.associateBy { it.id }
    val actual = oldDogsMap
            .filterKeys { newDogsMap.containsKey(it) }
            .map { newDogsMap[it.key]!! to it.value.second }

    assertEquals(expected, actual)
}
```

My question here is: What is a better way to write the code to get my `actual` variable? I especially dislike that I first filter the keys that are contained by *both* lists, but then I have to use `newDogsMap[it.key]!!` explicitly to get the null-safe values.

How can I improve it?

### Edit: Problem redefined

Updated thanks to Marko: I want to do an intersection, not a union.
What is easy is to do an intersection on lists:

```
val list1 = listOf(1, 2, 3)
val list2 = listOf(4, 3, 2)
list1.intersect(list2)
// [2, 3]
```

But what I actually want is an intersection on maps:

```
val map1 = mapOf(1 to true, 2 to false, 3 to true)
val map2 = mapOf(4 to "four", 3 to "three", 2 to "two")
// TODO: how to do get the intersection of maps?
// For example something like:
// [2 to Pair(false, "two"), 3 to Pair(true, "three")]
```

Comment: You say "union" but your code does an intersection. `expected` contains only the updated entries (that both existed already and are a part of the updated batch).

Comment: You are right - I want to do an intersection. But what I need is an intersection on maps - as far as I know Kotlin only supports intersection on lists.

Comment: If both of your maps contain equal value types, you can use `merge` as long as you have a `MutableMap`. If you haven't and you do not want to work with `null`-safe-operators, then I don't know any simpler approach then the one shown. It just gets more complicated instead or you write more code and I don't think that it gets more readable by omitting another `null`-safe-operator ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
val actual = oldDogsMap.flatMap { oDEntry ->
        newDogsMap.filterKeys { oDEntry.key == it }
                .map { it.value to oDEntry.value.second }
    }
```

Note that I only concentrated on the "how do you omit the `!!` in here" ;-)

Or the other way around works of course too:

```
val actual = newDogsMap.flatMap { nDE ->
        oldDogsMap.filterKeys { nDE.key == it }
                .map { nDE.value to it.value.second }
    }
```

You just need to have the appropriate outer entry available and you are (`null`-)safe.

That way you spare all those `null`-safe operations (e.g. `!!`, `?.`, `mapNotNull`, `firstOrNull()`, etc.).

Another approach is to add `cute` as a property to the `data class Dog` and use a `MutableMap` for the new dogs instead. This way you can `merge` the values appropriately using your own merge-function. But as you said in comments, you do not want a `MutableMap`, so that's not going to work then.

If you don't like what's going on here and rather want to hide it to anyone, you can also just supply an appropriate extension function. But naming it may already not be so easy... Here is an example:

```
inline fun <K, V, W, T> Map<K, V>.intersectByKeyAndMap(otherMap : Map<K, W>, transformationFunction : (V, W) -> T) = flatMap { oldEntry ->
        otherMap.filterKeys { it == oldEntry.key }
                .map { transformationFunction(oldEntry.value, it.value) }
}
```

And now you can call this function anywhere you want to intersect maps by their keys and immediately map to some other value, like the following:

```
val actual = oldDogsMap.intersectByKeyAndMap(newDogsMap) { old, new -> new to old.second }
```

Note that I am not a huge fan of the naming yet. But you will get the point ;-) All the callers of the function have a nice/short interface and don't need to understand how it's really implemented. The maintainer of the function however should of course test it accordingly.

Maybe also something like the following helps? Now we introduce an intermediate object just to get the naming better... Still not that convinced, but maybe it helps someone:

```
class IntersectedMapIntermediate<K, V, W>(val map1 : Map<K, V>, val map2 : Map<K, W>) {
    inline fun <reified T> mappingValuesTo(transformation: (V, W) -> T) = map1.flatMap { oldEntry ->
        map2.filterKeys { it == oldEntry.key }
                .map { transformation(oldEntry.value, it.value) }
    }
}
fun <K, V, W> Map<K, V>.intersectByKey(otherMap : Map<K, W>) = IntersectedMapIntermediate(this, otherMap)
```

If you go this route, you should rather take care of what the intermediate object should really be allowed to do, e.g. now I can take `map1` or `map2` out of that intermediate, which might not be appropriate if I look at its name... so we have the next construction site ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I like it because it solves my issue to not handle nullability explicitly - and it works! Still I wonder if it could be better readability-wise - I'm pretty sure a future me would stumble over this code and wonder what it does.
As Marko pointed out, I want to do an intersection - though Kotlin does only provide an intersection of iterables.
Something like `oldIds.intersect(newIds)` works, but I would need `oldDogsMap.intersect(newDogsMap)` that returns a map containing a pair of both values. Is there a function that does that?

Comment: Well there is something similar, but with your current `data class` or the setup you have it isn't doable that easily. I will update my answer to show you another approach, that might work for you, i.e. by adding `cute` as a property to `Dog`.

Comment: This is just my badly made example - the `Dog` class can't (and shouldn't) contain its meta info, because that is just used at one point in the code.

Comment: well... if it could, you could do the whole example using a `MutableMap` and its `merge`-method. If you don't, then... well.. you could still ensure that it looks as two equal maps (e.g. both contain a `Pair` even though the `Pair` of the second contains `null` as values... ) ... but then you wouldn't win so much ;-)

Comment: If you do not want to enhance the `data class`, nor use a `MutableMap` then I would rather hide all that functionality in the first place (extension function?) and so the callers see nice code, whereas the maintainer needs to ensure the functionality with appropriate tests... Win-win for all ;-) I updated the answer in that regard....

Comment: I ended up using your solution with the extension function - in the end I called it `intersectWith`. As Marko pointed out the implementation could use a mutable map for performance, but for now I went with the `flatMap` solution.
Code here for anyone who needs an `intersectWith` function in the future: https://gist.github.com/mreichelt/a6e4b85c204962e4f1248324ec3bb418

Comment: I thought so too at the beginning... :-) But when calling a simple `intersect` I would expect the two maps to be intersected, but what would this even mean with maps? So I thought adding `byKey` makes probably sense. Then again I thought I would probably rather expect a `Map` as return value, but we return a `List` now. So playing around I ended up with `intersectByKeyAndMap`; again: I am not so convinced about it. But to be honest, `intersectWith` seems also a bit misleading to me... (how about: `map1.intersectByKey(map2).mappingTo(transform)`?) ...but that's a total different issue... ;-)

Comment: You're right - and I would expect an `intersectByKey` or `intersectWith` method to return a `Map` as well, not a `List`. I'll update the code soon™ :-)

Comment: hmm... however the intersectBykey can't return the map directly, as you do not know how to transform it... Constructing a map where you do not need any, isn't that helpful neither... That is probably the reason, why the `merge` works on single keys/values and accepts a transformation function :-) I updated the answer to show one of many possible intermediate-object solutions ;-) The more I think of it... we do things we shouldn't do... setup your data class accordingly and it will all work out better ;-)

Answer (score 2):

To simplify things, let's say you have the following:

```
val data = mutableMapOf("a" to 1, "b" to 2)
val updateBatch = mapOf("a" to 10, "c" to 3)
```

The best option in terms of memory and performance is to update the entries directly in the mutable map:

```
data.entries.forEach { entry ->
    updateBatch[entry.key]?.also { entry.setValue(it) }
}
```

If you have a reason to stick to immutable maps, you'll have to allocate temporary objects and do more work overall. You can do it like this:

```
val data = mapOf("a" to 1, "b" to 2)
val updateBatch = mapOf("a" to 10, "c" to 3)

val updates = updateBatch
        .filterKeys(data::containsKey)
        .mapValues { computeNewVal(data[it.key]) }
val newData = data + updates
```

Comment: This looks elegant, but it removes data of the first map that I need to be preserved. I don't want to replace the data entirely, but I want to keep some meta info on it.

Comment: Instead of `entry.setValue(it)` you can write whatever you want to merge the new data into the old.

Comment: But it introduces mutability of the original map as well as the data class.

Comment: This is up to you to decide. Mutability is more efficient, but if you have a reason to keep everything immutable and copy the data, then you have to go with computing the intersection and then computing the new map from it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
val actual = dogsAreCute.map {cuteDog -> cuteDog to newDogs.firstOrNull { it.id ==  cuteDog.first.id } }
            .filter { it.second != null }
            .map { it.second to it.first.second }
```

This first pairs cute dogs to a new dog or null, then if there is a new dog, maps to the pair: new dog and cuteness information from the original map.

*Update*: Roland is right, this returns the type of `List<Pair<Dog?, Boolean>>`, so here is the proposed fix for the type for this approach:

```
val actual = dogsAreCute.mapNotNull { cuteDog ->
        newDogs.firstOrNull { it.id == cuteDog.first.id }?.let { cuteDog to it } }
            .map { it.second to it.first.second }
```

Most probably his approach in the other answer using `flatMap` is a more sophisticated solution.

Comment: But this returns `List<Pair<Dog?, Boolean>>` instead of `List<Pair<Dog, Boolean>>`... maybe not what the OP wanted...

Comment: You may require something like `dogsAreCute.mapNotNull {cuteDog -> newDogs.firstOrNull { it.id ==  cuteDog.first.id }?.let { cuteDog to it } }.map { it.second to it.first.second }` instead... However then you just replaced the `!!` unsafe operator with some `?.`/`firstNotNull`/`mapNotNull` safe operators, which might not be as readable as the `!!` itself...

Comment: @Roland: Ah ye, you are right. I'm so spoiled by smart cast, I did not even check the actual return type :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
val intersection = map1.mapNotNull { (map1Key, map1Value) ->
    map2[map1Key]
        ?.let { map2Value -> map1Value to map2Value }
        ?.let { pair -> map1Key to pair }
}.toMap()
```